# Process.exit(0) vs break in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop, break

I'm trying to understand the difference between using **Process.exit(0)** versus **break** to exit a loop in Ruby. Can someone please explain?

Comment: One exits the enclosing scope (`break`) and one exits the entire process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `break` will just escape out of it's own scope. Imagine this:

```
loop do
  #something goes here
  break
end
```

In the above example the `break` scope is it's direct `loop` so the program will stop when that `break` is executed.

**Now imagine this example:**

```
loop do  #loop 1
  loop do   #loop 2
    #something goes here
    break
  end
end
```

In the above code `break` will only exit `loop` #2 and the rest of the code will continue to run, whereas `Process.exit` will terminate the entire script.